# Ubuntu 18.04 boot error: syntax error: unexpected end of file when loading .profile

Tags: boot, .profile

[image: Photo of screen with erroe]

I can't figure out what is wrong with my Ubuntu 18.04. I was trying to set a path for an application in my `.profile` and restarted the machine. Since then, I've been getting this error on the screen. I tried rebooting Ubuntu changing configuration from the boot menu via the DVD but yet nothing is happening.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `.profile` to your question?

Comment: I cannot access anything beyond the image that I have posted.

Comment: I've added a way for you to access `.profile` in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lines 32 and 33:

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching "

Somewhere on line 32 a `"` hasn't been closed (or opened), and it's causing an "unexpected end of file". It's hard to say what exactly needs to be changed without being able to read your `.profile`.

Since you can't get past this error, you'll need to switch to another console with `ctrl+alt+f1`. Login then open it up with `vim /home/moloy/.profile` to find the error and edit it.

(vim will show you which line your cursor is on at the bottom and hopefully make things easier to spot with syntax highlighting.)

Comment: I tried to re-install ubuntu by using a DVD by changing the boot menu priority, but it is not reading from the CD.

Comment: reboot the machine and enter emergency mode and mount file system as read and write and check /home/<username>/.profile file and comment or uncomment 32 line in that file.

Comment: That's separate issue, for another question. Unless you really want a fresh system, reinstalling isn't necessary.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm glad I could help. Those little syntax errors can be really annoying, especially if you're just starting to learn how linux works.